# Seeking recommendations for a task management framework

Tags: jira, workflow, airflow, operation

I am looking out for a framework that will support the following task management functionalities. These are the task that will be performed by a human contract worker.

1. All the tasks comprises of various steps which will act as a workflow. You cannot skip a step. Steps in these tasks are implemented at our end with various microservices, and we will want an integration of this tool with our services.
2. These contract workers themselves are in a hierarchy and we may get some segregation between them for task management.
3. Tasks will be allocated to the contract workers.
4. Maintain a history of tasks.

I've heard of various workflow management tools like apache airflow, spotify's Luigi etc. But I believe those are for data pipeline workflows, My requirement is for operations management workflows.

Are there any open source product available in market that will help us in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

I use and recommend [Restyaboard](https://restya.com/board). The All-in-one free tool for CRM, Project, Team, Time and Task Management. We use it daily for managing our project workflow.